# Display Folder and Sub Folder in Treeview without the files

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

What I need to do is to display the folder and sub folders on tree view. This should not include files inside or outside the folder. What I accomplish now is I have display the directory in tree view. What I need now is to remove the files.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFile" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnBrowse"
            runat="server" Text="Browse" OnClick="btnBrowse_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" Height="326px" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"
            NodeIndent="15" Width="292px">
            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                VerticalPadding="0px" />
            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="2px"
                NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        </asp:TreeView>
```

Code behind:

```
TreeNode onjParent = new TreeNode("D:\\", "D:\\");
                onjParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(onjParent);

                TreeView1.CollapseAll();
```

I just want to remove the leaf. And display only the folder and sub folder.
[image]

Comment: Where is that data stored? Is it possible to filter it before passing it to the tree view?

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to populate the Tree.